# Any Color Laser Multifunction can Scan-to-email without local email server on network?

Tags: email, printer, gmail, scanner

I am trying to get a color laser multi function center (MFC) for my very IT limited parents.

I only have one MUST HAVE feature:

> The Networked MFC can send emails out without an email server on the local network. Does not need any computer attached for the Scan-To-Email. It should try send the email from internet based services like gmail.

It's something like a commercial MFC that connect to a local email server to send the scanned material to an email address, but with better authentication.

My idea is that it can setup to use gmail's SMTP service (that can authenticate with SSL), so my mother can scan documents from home to my dad at work via email? They used to use Fax for this purpose but it's so slow and terrible quality.

Skip budget for now, I wanted to know what MFCs can do this.

Comment: That would be case for just about any device...? There’s nothing magic about the location of a mail server. As for SSL/TLS, that’s a different matter altogether.

Comment: Yes, any brand of Multi function printer. I tried my own Samsung CLX-3185FN, but can't pass authentication. I think it does not support SSL, only TLS.

Comment: TLS is fine too on Google. That being said, not being SSL-capable but supporting TLS would be rather unusual. Well, if that’s what this question is about, please update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input Daniel B.

After extensive search I found a workaround for my case. As I am using gmail, I can get scans with settings from this link:

[Sending mail from a printer, scanner or app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

What should work is to use the ISP's account and their SMTP settings. However my parents ISP utilizes Google mail, so only sending to gmails from above **aspmx.l.google.com** setup will work for the MFC (without authentication). The only trouble will be sending to non-gmail accounts.

Just can't understand why modern MFC's does not support SSL authentication... Assuming there is a local email server for home users is just non-sense.